# time input validation / when I input intime 10:30 or 9:30 both accepted but condition is not true in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, html

```js
foreach ( $period as $dt )
{
    $new=$dt->format("Y-m-d");
    $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM enginner_timesheet e, cz c
            WHERE e.enginner_name='$name'
               and c.fullname='$fullname'
               and e.date='$new' ");            
    $row2= mysql_fetch_array($sql1);

    $in_time=$row2["in_time"];
    // if the condition apply
    if ($in_time > "10:20")
          $in_time = "<font color='#FF0000'>" .$in_time. "</font>";
    //if the condition met than time font will be red

    echo "<td>".$in_time."-".$row2["out_time"]."-".$row2["other_details"]."</td>";
}
```

I want to require if the condition is true than font text will be red but my output differs. The value is shown in red but 10:23 shows in red and 9:23 also shows in red.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/pfm2zo9f9/  this is my Output Image Link

Comment: problem with your $in_time string. It will work fine if you check with 09:23 instead of 9:23

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
if(strtotime($in_time)>strtotime("10:20"))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Solved Thanks Tanvir

Comment: if(strtotime($in_time)>strtotime("10:20") or ($in_time)<strtotime("10:50"))
   {
    $mark='Late Mark';
   }if(strtotime($in_time)>strtotime("10:51") or ($in_time)<strtotime("12:50"))
   {
    $mark='half day';
   }

Comment: when i used this than shows me a same First if considered @tanvir

Comment: $in_time='11:40';
if( (strtotime($in_time) > strtotime("10:20")) && (strtotime($in_time)<strtotime("10:50"))) {
  $mark='Late Mark'; 
}
if((strtotime($in_time)>strtotime("10:51")) && (strtotime($in_time)<strtotime("12:50"))) {
 $mark='half day'; 
} @Black_Panthor